# Trying to get user info from guild.bans()

Tags: python-3.x, list, set, discord.py

How could I get the make a set/list from "User id", "name", and "discriminator" from `guild.bans()` which for my test server is `[BanEntry(reason=None, user=<User id=240608458888445953 name='xpoes' discriminator='9244' bot=False>), BanEntry(reason=None, user=<User id=298265521185488896 name='Mehvix 2' discriminator='6212' bot=False>)]`

My goal is for them to be able to work in this code

```
newlist = []
for item in bot:
    if item:
        item = "<:bottag:473742770671058964>"
    else:
        item = ""
    newlist.append(item)
bot = newlist

total = list((zip(userid, name, discriminator, bot)))

# Thanks to happypetsy on StackOverflow for helping me with this!
pretty_list = set()
for details in total:
    data = "• <@{}>{} ({}#{}) ".format(details[0], details[3], details[1], details[2])
    pretty_list.add(data)

await ctx.message.channel.send("**Ban list:** \n{}".format("\n".join(pretty_list)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Guild.bans`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild.bans) return a list of `BanEntry` objects. `BanEntry` is a `namedtuple` `(reason, user)`.  We're just interested in the `user` field.

```
@bot.command()
async def bans(ctx):
    bans = await ctx.guild.bans()
    pretty_list = ["• {0.id} ({0.name}#{0.discriminator})".format(entry.user) for entry in bans]
    await ctx.send("**Ban list:** \n{}".format("\n".join(pretty_list)))
```